# Is it possible to send mails using phpList from localhost

Tags: php, email, newsletter, phplist

I installed `phpList` on localhost to test it out but I am not able to send any mails.
Is it possible to do this from localhost. I am using WAMP.

I have installed it successfully and also configured some options.

These are other configurations I have done..

```
define("PHPMAILERHOST",'smtp.gmail.com:465');
$phpmailer_smtpuser = '######@gmail.com';
$phpmailer_smtppassword = '#####';
define('PHPMAILERPORT',465);
```

Any help will be highly appreciated. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Got it to work with PHPList 3.0.5

Here comes the `config/config.php` excerpt:

```
define("PHPMAILER",1);
define("PHPMAILERHOST",'smtp.gmail.com');
define("PHPMAILERPORT",'465');
$phpmailer_smtpsecure = 'ssl';
$phpmailer_smtpuser = 'user@gmail.com';
$phpmailer_smtppassword = 'pass';
$phpmailer_smtpport = '465';
```

Unfortunetely, I had also to edit the `admin/class.phplistmailer.php`:

1. I had to add `$this->SMTPSecure = $GLOBALS['phpmailer_smtpsecure'];` above each ocurrence of `$this->SMTPAuth = true;`
2. Comment each ocurrence the `$this->Helo = getConfig("website");`

I haven't replaced the PHPMailer 5.2.5 that comes with PHPList 3.0.5

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to test this and not use it as production on work localhost, I suggest you to install smtp4dev. This software catches all the emails that are sent on your local SMTP port (25) and you can see them in Outlook or whatever email software you want to test.